# To detect spam messages using imap php

Tags: php, imap

I am retriving my mails using php imap function.

I am retriving all messages from server and i need to know how to detect messages which are spam in my received mails.

**Question:** How to Detect spam in emails received using imap php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that is the job of your mail server admin, if you are him you will need to use a 3rd party software like SpamAssassin. The choise is up to you and your specific implementation of a mail server.

Comment: +1 for SpamAssassin suggestion... it can actually be called from PHP as well